# Is "the way how" wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

I was correcting an ESL learner who said "It is the way how we write."

I realize "It is the way we write" is correct and "It is how we write" is correct, but "It is the way how we write" *looks* wrong to me, despite that when I say it out loud it sounds perfectly normal if I'm speaking fast. What I mean is, if an ESL learner said it, it would sound wrong. But when I say it as a native speaker, it seems okay though not felicitous. So I can't tell.

Is it grammatically wrong?

Comment: It is incorrect because individually, both *the way* and *how* can be directly replaced by, for example, *the fashion in which*. But if you repeat that replacement, *It is the fashion in which the fashion in which we write* creates gibberish, not emphasis.

Comment: You're at odds with the answer below. How do I know who's right??

Comment: Obviously I think ***I'm*** right! But I don't know how to convince you - other than to point out that currently my comment has three upvotes, whereas MetaEd's answer has only one.

Comment: Hmm...a keen argument...

Comment: You could look at some actual [usage statistics](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+the+way+I%2Cis+how+I%2Cis+the+way+how+I&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=). That's **how|the way** I would approach it.

Comment: A little poking around in GB shows that *the way how* is occasionally to be found in the 17th century, but disappeared in the course of the 18th - most subsequent hits are republications of 17th century texts. It *could* be used quite as often as *the reason why* - but it isn't.

Comment: "The way how" is not currently accepted as idiomatic because, as FumbleFingers says, "the way" = "how" = "the fashion in which" = "the manner in which": the phrase "the way how" is irredeemably redundant. "The reason why", structurally similar and equally redundant, is an accepted idiom despite (or maybe because of) its idiocy. It has been given the amazing grace of the English gods.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: an argument from redundancy or more generally from logic, hardly ever has any weight in establishing grammaticality. (Obviously, in many cases they do point in the same direction, but not reliably).

Comment: @Colin: Granted, in the final analysis grammaticality is just "what we say". And it's true that 2-3 centuries ago we *did* used to speak of [the way how to (do something)](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+way+how+to&year_start=1730&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). But we don't today, so *currently* it's "ungrammatical". I'm just saying why I personally don't like it, and obviously some others agree with me. Collectively it's obviously avoided because people "don't like it", whatever their individual reasons.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: that's an invalid argument. For example, *when* means *the time at which*. So *remember the time when* becomes *remember the time the time at which*, which sounds just as ridiculous as *the fashion in which the fashion in which.* But there's nothing grammatically wrong with *the time when*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *The place where, the time when,* and *the person who* are all perfectly valid in English. It's only *the reason why* and *the way how* that aren't used.  Don't ask me the reason why; it's just the way how we speak.

Comment: @PeterShor: As user21497 wrote (long ago), ***The reason why** ... is an accepted idiom despite (or maybe because of) its idiocy*. ("Idiocy begets idiomacy", so to speak! :) I wasn't trying to promote some syntactically / semantically coherent argument / rationale with a view to persuading anyone else that they should avoid using ***the way how*** for the reasons ***I*** don't like it! I was just saying that's how I view things. Obviously in reality the reason ***I*** don't use ***the way how*** myself is the same as everyone else's reason: we don't hear it, so it sounds weird, so we avoid it.

Answer (score 9):

It’s not grammatically wrong, just unconventional. Most people would use the connecting word *that*:

> It is the way *that* we write.

You could also see:

> It is the way *in which* we write.

You can, for example, compare the relative frequency of these phrases in print using *Google Ngram Viewer*. The chart below compares “is the way how”, “is the way that”, and “is the way in which”. It appears from the chart that “is the way how” is virtually never seen in print. The other two are seen regularly, but for the past 200 years “is the way in which” has been more popular.

[image]

Click on the chart to interact with it. You can, for example, separate the results for British and American English.

Answer (score 0):

'The way' and 'how' are not used together.
It is how we write.
Or
It is the way we write.

"The way how" is redundant as well as unconventional.

Answer (score -2):

This is not the way how we want to win".
The New York Times - Sports

"It's irony, a group of technology companies showing the way how to be human," he added.
The New York Times

The way how she does everything is different, and that's what I like".
The New York Times - Sports